# Antenna for detecting the direction of a signal source

Tags: antenna, hardware

I'm looking for an antenna that can detect the direction of another (transmitting) antenna.

Instead of only getting the signal strength and moving around, or turning a directional antenna around to find the strongest signal direction, I would like to have this antenna point me in the right direction by giving me a readout - it's X degrees clockwise and Y degrees elevation.

At the moment I don't even know what such an antenna would be called so searching the web is not bringing up anything useful.

(I checked the help page and it seemed like this question is appropriate here, but if I'm wrong, just let me know. I'm new here. Thanks.)

Comment: http://www.turnpoint.net/wireless/cantennahowto.html

Comment: @ThePhoton Great! You can transform your comment into an answer. (By the way, I was expecting some way using 3 or 4 antennae and measuring which got the signal first. But I guess electronics aren't _that_ accurate.)

Comment: Due to your specific requirement not to rotate the antenna, you are very close to asking a question about designing a system for what they call "war-driving" to find (open) networks. The legality or morality of such would be questionable. May be you can update your question to include your reasons why you do not want to rotate the antenna. Because an answer already given (cantenna) is probably the cheapest and most effective way to find your _"router somewhere in your house"_, which in itself is suspect as well; that you do not know where your router is... I have answered below as well.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo If you really suspected me of malicious intent - you shouldn't have posted an answer.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Absolutely not. That was prompted by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1063636/how-to-find-a-router-at-an-unknown-location-in-a-house). I turned to you hardware guys since I'm a [developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234100#234100) .

Comment: Your question can no longer be answered due to removal of constraints.  Perhaps the Square Kilometre Array might be suitable but it does stretch across a few continents.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_Kilometre_Array

Comment: @KalleMP :) Too small. I need some on the moon too.

Comment: @KalleMP, A much smaller phased array should be adequate if OP doesn't need milliarcsecond directional precision. Obviously we can only give general answers (as in my post) without more details about the requirements, but I still think we can give *useful* answers.

Comment: @ispiro, I asked you to update your question with reasoning why you are asking for a "non rotatable system". I asked you to do this to **take away** suspicion ! -- your choice. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the direction of an antenna without physically moving it, you can use a *phased-array* antenna. This means using several antennas and adjusting the phase of the signal at each one so that they produce constructive interference in a preferred direction and destructive interference in other directions. By reciprocity, the same principle can be applied to receiving as to transmitting.

If using a phased array for direction finding, rather than simply sweeping the direction of the antenna, you can use a signal processing algorithm to effectively search all directions simultaneously. Two well-known algorithms for direction finding are *MUSIC* and *ESPRIT*.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't even know what such an antenna would be called

Well, it sounds a bit that you want to do a bit of "Radio Direction Finding" which is actually a (radio) sport. Many systems have been invented.

One which is popular, which multiple static antennas to get an azimuth reading for the direction the signal is coming from is called a "*Doppler Antenna Array*".

[Here](http://www.homingin.com/newdopant.html) some info on such.

**However** these type of systems are usually used with frequencies around 145 MHz or 435 MHz. It would take some re-engineering to make such systems work for 2.4 GHz, and with tolerances which actually would give a useful reading.

Not sure how you would get elevation with a non-rotatable antenna system. Maybe a second Doppler array stacked on top of each other, in theory this could work, but you will have to be carefull in regards to gain patterns which are already elevated for vertical antennas.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Directional antenna.

Look up Pringles Tin antenna for WiFi experiments.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna

Comment: Thanks. +1 because I _did_ write "**Preferably** without having to turn the antenna around". But what I'm really looking for is something that can read a direction without having to be turned around.

Comment: @ispiro You really do like moving the goalposts with your in body edits of the question.

Comment: Point taken. I wasn't clear enough. By the way, I did not remove my upvote. You still have a +1 from me. Someone else must have downvoted, and probably did not read my comment.